# Taking the difference between current and previous data via Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table on MS Access 2010 that has data similar to the following with two columns DateLog and GenKW:

```
DateLog    | GenKW
-------------------
04/28/2015 | 6696.0
04/29/2015 | 6806.0
04/30/2015 | 6921.0
05/01/2015 | 7037.0
```

I want to take the difference between the two and get an output similar to:

```
Date        | GrossKW
--------------------
04/29/2015  | 110.0
04/30/2015  | 115.0
05/01/2015  | 116.0
```

I'm new to Visual Basic and Access so I came up with the following but I'm getting a Null value error on variable 'Crnt'.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub SubPrev()
Dim rsSS As DAO.Recordset, rsPV As DAO.Recordset
Dim Crnt As Long, Prev As Long, Gross As Long

Set rsSS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT * FROM [tbl_K4_Switchbrd_Log]", _
        dbOpenSnapshot)

Do Until rsSS.EOF
    Crnt = rsSS!Opr_Emp_ID
    Gross = Crnt - Prev
    rsSS.MoveNext
Loop
rsSS.Close
rsPV.Close
Set rsSS = Nothing
Set rsPV = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get dataset with already calculated difference between dates

try this:

```
Sub SubPrev()
Dim rsSS As DAO.Recordset

Set rsSS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
"SELECT L.Date_log, " & _
       "(L.GenKW - R.GenKW) AS GrossKW " & _
"FROM tbl_K4_Switchbrd_Log AS L " & _
"INNER JOIN tbl_K4_Switchbrd_Log AS R " & _
"ON L.Date_log = DATEADD('d',1,R.Date_log)", _
        dbOpenSnapshot)

Debug.Print rsSS(0).Name, rsSS(1).Name
Do Until rsSS.EOF
    Debug.Print rsSS(0), rsSS(1)
    rsSS.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

test is below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you need to update existed table field then use this code:

```
Sub SubPrev()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database, sql$, i&
Set dbs = CurrentDb
sql = "UPDATE (SELECT L.Date_log , ( L.GenKW - R.GenKW ) AS GrossKW " & _
      "FROM   tbl_K4_Switchbrd_Log AS L  INNER JOIN tbl_K4_Switchbrd_Log AS R " & _
      "ON L.Date_log = DATEADD('d', 1, R.Date_log)) as T " & _
      "INNER JOIN tbl_K4_Switchbrd_Log ON tbl_K4_Switchbrd_Log.Date_log = T.Date_log " & _
      "Set Gross = GrossKW"
dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
MsgBox dbs.RecordsAffected & " rows affected "
End Sub
```

test below:

*before update*

[image]

*after update*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Unfortunately my data doesn't have a unique ID field.  Is there a way around this or do I have to add a unique ID?

Comment: There is no difference whether you have a unique id for each record or not,because the link goes by date. The problem can be if you have duplicated date, in this case you need to summarize value by date to get unique date with sum of value by this date, and after that get linkage between dates.

Comment: Thanks Vasily!  This works even without the unique id.  I'm also trying to append it to the next column of my current table with the calculated output.  Would I just add instead of the 'debug.print' code something similar to:
Set fldNew = tblTest.CreateField(strField, dbLong)
tblTest.Fields.Append fldNew